# Метод remove() оставляет объекты

Tags: java, итераторы, delete

Есть и другие способы удаления, но столкнулся с непонятной для меня задачей.

Простой пример. Сделал лист, вывел его содержимое. После чего создал итератор и удалил все элементы листа. После чего вывел лист тремя способами.

```
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add("Ivan");
        list.add("Petr");
        list.add("Mary");
        list.add("Oleg");
        
        System.out.println(list);
        
        Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator.next();
            iterator.remove();
        }

        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        
        for (String s : list) {
            System.out.print(s + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println(list);
```

> Output:
> [Ivan, Petr, Mary, Oleg]
> .
> .
> []

Но вот когда я вывожу список через итератор, перед методом remove(), я получаю не удаленный список.

```
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add("Ivan");
        list.add("Petr");
        list.add("Mary");
        list.add("Oleg");
        
        System.out.println(list);
        
        Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();

        // add:
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");
        }

        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator.next();
            iterator.remove();
        }

        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        
        for (String s : list) {
            System.out.print(s + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println(list);
```

> Output:
> [Ivan, Petr, Mary, Oleg]
> Ivan Petr Mary Oleg
> Ivan Petr Mary Oleg
> [Ivan, Petr, Mary, Oleg]

Я не могу понять смысл появления или не удаление листа после обычного перебора. Решения я так и не нашел, поэтому буду рад ответу или ссылку где можно найти ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что здесь

```
// add:
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
      System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");
}
```

Вы дошли до конца (курсор показывает на последний элемент в коллекции)

И при попытке *все удалить*.

```
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
     iterator.next();
     iterator.remove();
}
```

`iterator.hasNext()` Возвращает `false`, так как итератор *изжил свое*, необходимо создавать новый.

Comment: Если что-то не так или не понятно, буду рад дополнить ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо) Я даже не подозревал о таком поведении итератора и думал что он попросту сбрасывается в начало.

Comment: @AlexeyKonovalov для понимания можете себе представить клетки в ряд, в каждой клетке есть значение, для того чтобы получить значение в клетке, необходимо указать на нее, назовем это курсором. С помощью `iterator.next()` можно передвигать курсор, а для проверки есть ли там что-то еще есть 'iterator.hasNext()` Курсор двигается только в 1 направлении

Comment: А как тогда предупредить себя о его использовании, так как exception он выкидывает при других, более понятных случаях. Я вывел два повторных перебора и он конечно вывел только один список.

Comment: @AlexeyKonovalov не понял вопроса

Comment: я перечитал информацию из разных источников по итератору и так не нашел упоминаний о его "одноразовом использовании". Но ведь может возникнуть проблема, когда надо будет удалить через remove() значение в списке, а он уже будет "пуст".

Comment: @AlexeyKonovalov вообще для удаления всех элементов или 1 элемента коллекции существуют методы у самой коллекции, например у `List` это `clear` и `remove` соответсвенно.

Comment: @AlexeyKonovalov насчет "одноразовом использовании" следует из-за того что у вас нет возможности вернутся назад, только вперед    :). А метод `list.iterator()` создает каждый раз новый Iterator.